# Trouble with Parse + Swift ft. Optionals

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, types, option-type

I'm having a bit of trouble with the second function, but since it references the first one, I'm including both. I've been playing around with the optionals (? and !) and casting to no avail, getting the 'Cannot assign immutable value of type 'AnyObject?!' among others. Thanks.

```
func getRequestForName(name: NSString) -> AnyObject{
    for r in requests{
        if(r["from"] as? NSString == name || r["to"] as? NSString == name){
            return r
        }
    }
}
func acceptRequestForName(name: NSString){
    var r: AnyObject = getRequestForName(name)
    r["status"] = "accepted" as AnyObject?!
    r.saveEventually()
}
```

Comment: where is the requests variable in your code , its no where there?

Comment: the requests is a class variable. it's an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
func getRequestForName(name: NSString, requests:[AnyObject]) -> AnyObject{
    for r in requests{
        if(r["from"] as? NSString == name || r["to"] as? NSString == name){
            return r
        }
    }
}


func acceptRequestForName(name: NSString){
    var r: AnyObject = getRequestForName(name,requests) //please declare an array of anyObject before using it here
    r["status"] = "accepted" as AnyObject
    r.saveEventually()
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a cannot assign to immutable value of type AnyObject?!

Comment: in the getRequestForName method please understand you are using "r" value itself as an array which makes the "requests" variable an array of array of Anyobject . Now you are returning "r" from that method which is of type [AnyObject] but while declaring the method you have specified the method returns type 'AnyObject" and not "[AnyObject]"